# CSS not loaded correctly inside Project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use `glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign`

For this I am using below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And this is working for me.

When I copy CSS from above URL and create one `bootstrap.min.css` file in my Project inside `css` folder and use below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

But it's not working. I am getting below error on console
[image]

Please help me to fix this.

I am using AngularJS, Bootstrap v3.3.7.

Comment: @neptune I just run this from my local.

Comment: Did you also download the glyphicons and put them in the correct path ../fonts/ relative from your css?

Comment: Restart the server. Clear browser cache

Comment: @mainguy No. Please suggest how can I download this?

Comment: Find full instructions here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only copy CSS file and missing font files (in CDN, they use relative path to font folder)

You can download Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/ and copy font folder to your project.

Or fix the path in CSS file by replace all `../fonts/` with full path `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/`

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file you copied from the CDN use relative paths for those resources you are getting errors. Do not copy dependencies from CDN-s directly. Try to get them through a dependency handler or add them as described in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `bootstrap` CSS you mentioned(non minified version) refers to few font files which looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Meaning you need to have these "font files" in a directory named `fonts` in the **same level as your bootstrap css file**.

Since you are using a minified version(`.min.css`), don't try to alter the path in your css file rather place the necessary font files in the location the css is looking for.